# Discrepancies with Actual vs Expected Probabilities for Distribution?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, fat-tails

I am attempting to estimate consecutive days worth of sales of specific items in each store:

For most stores, the probability (n=1 k=1, n=2 k=2, etc…) that an item will continue to sell over a period of n-consecutive days approximately fits a binomial distribution.  Therefore, at most stores, the probability of n-consecutive days of sales can be derived from the actual (historical) probability of one day of sales.

However, for a subset of locations (in the same geographical region), the sales data are well above the modeled binomial data and are heavily fat-tailed; approximately ~2 orders of magnitude more probable to be sold in a consecutive fashion than the predicted binomial distribution suggests. The skewness and kurtosis are non-infinite, and an internal assessment determined that there could be some dependency. This is negligible in the well-modeled stores but could potentially cause an issue for the poorly modeled stores.

It would be of great assistance if another distribution or approach could be suggested to better model the high-probability tail events.

Example:

Binomial:

```
+----------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Location | N=1  | N=2 | N=3 | N=4 | N=5 | N=6 | N=7 | N=8 |
+----------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| I        |  509 |  81 |  18 |   4 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| J        |  509 |  81 |  18 |   4 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| K        |  721 | 133 |  34 |  11 |   4 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| L        |  463 |  71 |  17 |   3 |   2 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| M        |  312 |  49 |  10 |   2 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| N        |  431 |  64 |  12 |   3 |   2 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| O        |  685 | 111 |  31 |   7 |   3 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| P        |  580 | 108 |  23 |   6 |   2 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
| Q        | 1142 | 226 |  65 |  24 |   6 |   3 |   0 |   0 |
+----------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Fat-tailed

```
+----------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Location | N=1  | N=2 | N=3 | N=4 | N=5 | N=6 | N=7 | N=8 |
+----------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| A        | 1127 | 239 | 136 |  75 |  42 |  23 |  16 |  11 |
| B        | 2223 | 488 | 227 | 113 |  54 |  32 |  20 |  11 |
| C        |  925 | 172 |  87 |  46 |  30 |  20 |  15 |   9 |
| D        |  925 | 172 |  87 |  46 |  30 |  20 |  15 |   9 |
| E        |  861 | 166 |  87 |  46 |  24 |  15 |  12 |   8 |
| F        |  705 | 160 |  92 |  50 |  26 |  16 |   9 |   8 |
| G        | 1047 | 249 | 126 |  55 |  30 |  20 |  12 |   5 |
| H        | 1402 | 307 | 130 |  58 |  35 |  22 |  11 |   5 |
+----------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

This image shows the discrepancy between values predicted from N=1 using the binomial distribution (theoretical) and the actual values for fat-tailed locations.

[image: Actual vs Theoretical sales for fat-tailed store]

Comment: Maybe your underlying model is wrong, maybe this does not follow a binomial distribution. Have you tried others?

Comment: Other distributions is what I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: Without some data I can only guess. Try negative binomial, geometric, Poisson.

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks for your suggestions. I added an example of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the binomial distribution we could try other discrete ones, such as geometric, Poisson, Negative Binomial, Discrete Weibull, Beta Binomial, etc..

Here is my attempt at solving this using the binomial, geometric and beta binomial distributions. To estimate the parameters of these distributions I will use the maximum likelihood estimators. I will plot the results of the examples that you posted in your question under fat tailed distributions.

In black I will present the distribution of the data, red curve is the estimated binomial, blue is geometric and green is beta binomial. These are the results

[image]

As you can see, the beta binomial distribution fits quite nicely, since it is a two parameter distribution, with an additional parameter over the binomial distribution accounting for the overdispersion.

**Edit:** my code written in R.

I save the data in a list named `dat`. What follows is a simple for loop for every letter A to H. For each letter I use `optim` to numerically estimate the parameter(s) for the given distribution using maximum likelihood estimation - that is maximizing log likelihood (this is not really necessary for all of them, since some of them have analytical solutions, but given your sample size, this will hardly make any difference). I save the estimated parameters in the data frame `res`.

```
dat=list(
  A=rep(0:7,times=c(1127,239,136,75,42,23,16,11)),
  B=rep(0:7,times=c(2223,488,227,113,54,32,20,11)),
  C=rep(0:7,times=c(925,172,87,46,30,20,15,9)),
  D=rep(0:7,times=c(925,172,87,46,30,20,15,9)),
  E=rep(0:7,times=c(861,166,87,46,24,15,12,8)),
  F=rep(0:7,times=c(705,160,92,50,26,16,9,8)),
  G=rep(0:7,times=c(1047,249,126,55,30,20,12,5)),
  H=rep(0:7,times=c(1402,307,130,58,35,22,11,5))
)

library(VGAM)

res=data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(dat)) {
  t1=optim(par=0.1,fn=function(x){-sum(dgeom(dat[[i]],x,log=T))},
           method="Brent",lower=1/1e10,upper=1)$par
  t2=optim(par=0.1,fn=function(x){-sum(dbinom(dat[[i]],length(dat[[i]]),x,log=T))},
           method="Brent",lower=1/1e10,upper=1)$par
  t3=optim(par=c(0.5,0.5),fn=function(x){
    -sum(VGAM::dbetabinom(dat[[i]],length(dat[[i]]),x[1],x[2],log=T))})$par        

  res=rbind(res,c(t1,t2,t3))
}

rownames(res)=names(dat)
colnames(res)=c("geometric","binomial","betabinomial1","betabinomial2")
round(res,5)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a ton. I want to give it a bit more time to let other people answer before giving you the bounty and marking it as answered. I'd love to see the code if possible.